# jQuery Handling JSON responses

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following from the server response:

```
{"invalid_emails":["adsasdasd"],"result":"success","valid_emails":["jobs@apple.com"]}
```

But this errors?

```
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/users/invitation',
                data: $('#user_invitation_new').serialize(),
                success: function(e) {
                    jsonObject = jQuery.parseJSON(e);
                    jsonObject.valid_emails
                    jsonObject.invalid_emails
```

**I get the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'valid_emails' of null**

Comment: Are you able to read other properties ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Jason and Jonathon mentioned, you should not manually deserialize the JSON.  Depending on what version of jQuery you're using, jQuery will automatically deserialize JSON based on the response's content-type header.  So, you're probably trying to $.parseJSON() something that's already an object, not a JSON string.

To be sure that jQuery does this automatic deserialization for you, add a `dataType` parameter to the $.ajax() call:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  url: '/users/invitation',
  data: $('#user_invitation_new').serialize(),
  success: function(response) {
    console.log(response.valid_emails);
    console.log(response.invalid_emails);
  }
});
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out the content-type header--really helped me out!!

Answer (score 2):

You may not have to parse that JSON, as it is already a JSON object. try doing

```
var emails = e.valid_emails;
```

If this still does not work, include `dataType: 'json'` in your `.ajax()` declaration.

Answer (score 0):

If your server responds with the JSON then you should have to run `jQuery.parseJSON(e);`. The `e` parameter might already be the about so try this for your success handler:

```
success: function(e)
    var valEmails = e.valid_emails,
        invalEmails = e.invalid_emails;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try including

```
dataType: 'json',
```